# Single photons created by different lasers

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have been reading the chapter on Bell inequalities in Peres's Quantum Theory book (pgs 168-169) where the author mentions that one can create single photons with different lasers. Can anyone explain how this can be done? Some experimental setup would be useful to help me understand this strange situation.

Comment: I think this needs a bit more context - not everyone has the text at hand, and otherzise it is not clear what teh question is about.

Comment: While there are 'true' single photon sources (e.g. nitrogen-vacancy center in diamond), one can get 'single photons' from lasers by attenuating them to the point where, in a given time period $t$ less than 1 photon will emerge from the laser (note you want less than so the chance of 2 photons is low). Yes, that means that you get 0 photons many times...

Answer (score 0):

One experimental method for creating *heralded* single photons is by using [spontaneous parametric down-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion). The basic idea there is that a photon incident on a nonlinear crystal with a particular type of nonlinearity will sometimes ("spontaneously") convert ("down-convert") into two photons, whose total energy and momentum sum to that of the initial photon. Then, since the two photons' momenta may point in different directions, one can set up a detector to look for a photon being emitted in a certain direction. When this idealized detector notices a photon, it means that there was a down-conversion event, and you can use the second photon in the pair as a single photon for your experiments.

In general, one uses a strong laser as the incident beam, and occasionaly one of the photons in that beam down-converts into two lower-energy photons. This process is not deterministic, but can be used reliably to produce single photons by constantly looking for one from the pair, because once you notice one photon you are guaranteed that a second photon also exists.

There are a number of caveats and simplifications that are not too relevant to understanding this answer. E.g., occasionally, there may be events that produce quadruplets of photons instead of pairs of photons, but those are less common; also, the detector heralding the presence of a single photon must not give many spurious results.

This idea is explained briefly on the relevant wiki page on [single-photon sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_source) but without much detail.